# What is a good way to present data in a bar-chart when the spacing between bars isn't equal?

Tags: data-visualization

I have some MATLAB data; the first column is some message length, and the second column is how often that length occurs. Something like this:

```
15   1
40  12
200  5
215  2
```

My first instinct to visualize this data was to put it in a bar graph, as so:

[image: bar graph]

The problem with bar graphs, though, is that there is an implied equal spacing. In the case of the picture above, there is an interval of 10 units (presumably years in this case) from bar to bar.

My data does not have equal spacing everywhere, as shown in the example above. And the range of the message lengths is large; one chunk of data I just processed has a range of 44 to 7756 with very irregular spacing (anywhere between 10 and 1000 apart). I don't think a histogram is the right choice here either, since the data I'm looking at are so irregularly spaced, there's no good choice of bin size.

How should I go about visualizing this data?

Comment: Note that histograms are *not* bar charts: bar charts represent quantities by length while histograms represent them by area.  The difference therefore shows up when you construct a histogram using bins of unequal width. Have you considered that option?

Comment: @whuber no I haven't. That's a good point that I'll have to think about.

Comment: There is no problem in principle about a histogram with some, or even many, bars of zero height. Such bars merely represent values not observed in the data, and such gaps are part of what you want to show. Alternatively, consider quantile plots as discussed at e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0018

Comment: @NickCox It's not a huge problem to have many many bars of zero height, but it'd be a pain to have to print out the histogram on banner paper for people to look at it :)

Comment: That doesn't follow. Printing bars of zero height takes zero ink. But I made another suggestion too, quantile plots.

Comment: @Nick The OP is referring to the large range of values and the likelihood that much of the histogram's area will be concentrated in a few locations. Ink is not the issue; perception is. Options include transforming the values (e.g., using logarithms, with all that entails for interpretation) or alternative plots such as you are suggesting.

Comment: The ink comment was intended as a joke. Clearly it didn't work.... If message length is positive (sounds right, but I don't know the exact rules), then transformation is certainly a possibility and is compatible with other ideas.

Comment: Rephrase: if message length is zero or positive, square or cube root transformation might well help; if positive, add logarithms to the list, and try them first.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a scatter plot, but if length-encoding is important, you can use what's sometimes called a needle plot, which uses a vertical line from the axis to each point. Here's a plot of the 4 pairs you give in your example.

[image]